# Covert date and time to weekday [YY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss to weekends]

Tags: bash, date, time

i have data which is csv as below, i need to create weekday columns based on "date" column.

```
date,user,status
2022-10-31T06:28:16+09:00,JACK,login
2022-10-27T11:43:36+09:00,PETER,login
2022-10-26T07:11:19+09:00,MIKE,notlogin
2022-10-22T23:42:46+09:00,KANE,login
2022-10-21T00:12:38+09:00,VINI,notlogin
```

i required to add one more column as weekday , 2022-10-31 is monday .. as shown below

```
date,user,status,day,weekday
2022-10-31T06:28:16+09:00,JACK,login,monday
2022-10-27T11:43:36+09:00,PETER,login,thursday
2022-10-26T07:11:19+09:00,MIKE,notlogin,wednesday
2022-10-22T23:42:46+09:00,KANE,login,saturday
2022-10-21T00:12:38+09:00,VINI,notlogin,monday
```

**Taken from comments**

I have tried using

```
$ cat data | awk -F "," '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>1' | awk -F "T" '{print $1}'
```

but im not much aware where to pass `date -d YY-mm-dd "+%A"` command

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: @HatLess, im not good in bash script, could you please help to get desired-ouput ?
i was doing grepping of date columns and trying to coverting int-to weekday, but its not printing the output. 

**cat data | awk -F "," '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>1' | awk -F "T" '{print $1}'** 

but im not much aware where to pass **date -d YY-mm-dd "+%A"** command

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^[0-9]/{s/([^T]*).*/echo &,$(date -d '\\1' +'%A')/e};s/,[[:alpha:]]+$/\L&/;1s/$/,day,weekday/' input_file
date,user,status,day,weekday
2022-10-31T06:28:16+09:00,JACK,login,monday
2022-10-27T11:43:36+09:00,PETER,login,thursday
2022-10-26T07:11:19+09:00,MIKE,notlogin,wednesday
2022-10-22T23:42:46+09:00,KANE,login,saturday
2022-10-21T00:12:38+09:00,VINI,notlogin,friday
```